# What kind of pattern design would apply?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, uml

this statement asks me what kind of design pattern applied, firstly , tell me what to build toys, as they are only 3 types of play, and none is related eg with some color, would apply the factory method.

But apart it tells me that the Toys can be turned off and on, which makes me think that this would be a command pattern (or state).

I can mix 2 patterns in a final solution?

> We want to build 3 kinds of toys : Pokemon , Barbie and Superman . They feature animation actions associated with their off and on , these actions are different for each type of toy. Explain what design pattern and would use the class diagram Perform final design .

thanks

Comment: What 2 patterns do you think should be mixed?

Comment: I thought mix the factory pattern (to create toys ) to create toys, and pattern command ( on and off toys), to model the behavior of toys.

Comment: That's perfectly ok. The answer from @akash actually does not show the factory pattern but the command  pattern but this part is fine.

Comment: This seems a lot like a homework question. Is it homework?

Comment: @Makaveli...do accept the answer if you find it helpful !

Answer (score 0):

You can mainly take the approach of using the 'Abstract Factory Pattern'.

This is how you should do the implementation

Declare an interface ShowAnimation

```
public interface ShowAnimation{
  public void onState();
  public void offState();
}
```

Then inside each of your Pokemon , Barbie and Superman classes, you will simply implement this ShowAnimation interface and override the onState and offState methods as per your business logic.
This way

```
public class Barbie implements ShowAnimation{
  @override
  public void onState(){
     System.out.println("Show dance");
  }

  @override
  public void offState(){
     System.out.println("Do Namaste");
  }

}
```

This entire pattern you term as Abstract Factory Design Pattern.

Follow this link for more reference
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/abstract_factory_pattern.htm

Edit 1-
I would like to update my answer
"This is the Command Pattern that you will use using an interface and implementing the interface, 
however, you can create a separate abstract class Toys

```
abstract public class Toys {
provide some basic functionalities for this Toy class
}
```

and make other concrete class Barbie to extend Toys and implement ShowAnimation

So, basically you can mix both 'Factory Pattern' as well as 'Command Pattern' to achieve this.

Comment: Actually the pattern you are using is not a factory pattern since you do not create any class at all. This patterns matches the command pattern, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the interface and implementation akash89 described except the `ShowAnimation` interface and its implementation is the **Strategy Pattern**. In the strategy pattern you'll have an interface with interchangeable implementations, in this case your toys.

The **State Pattern** assumes that the internal behaviour changes of the object when you call some method. This is not the case in question.

A normal **Factory Pattern** is more than enough. You'll just create objects with (in the case of akash89) the `ShowAnimation` interface on which you can call the on and off animations. (However I would change the interface to `IToy` because a toy factory would create toys, not ShowAnimations ;) )

An **Abstract Factory** will create factories itself. For example, you could have an abstract factory that will create a factory for boy-specific toys or a factory for girl-specific toys. Each factory will then create barbies, pokemons and/or a superman.